# Filter a list with AZ tabs (image explication)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

how can filter with AZ tabs in my list items?

[alt text http://www.pizarrayoro.com/az.gif](http://www.pizarrayoro.com/az.gif)

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand but maybe this will help.

```
Customer.find(:all, :conditions => { :name => 'a'..'e' })
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

If you need help with the controller or view specifically can you please add more information to your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
@items = Item.paginate :page => params[:page], :order => 'name', 
         :conditions=>["name LIKE ? or name LIKE ? or name LIKE ? or name like ?",  
         'A%', 'B%', 'C%', 'D%']
```

This will give what you want, but I am sure there is a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your controller and call it with ajax on tab switch

```
protected
  def alpha_list(start, finish)
    @items = Item.find(:all, :order => 'name',
                       :conditions => { :name => start..finish })
    @items
  end
```